# How to draw on perticulr child layout in layout hierarchy in android

Tags: android-layout

I am new to android. I had declare layout hierarchy in main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout class="com.android.MyLayout"
android:id="@+id/mylayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget36"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="42dp"
android:background="@color/darkgray"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget38"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="390dp"
android:background="@color/black"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also use this layout in my java class

```
 class MyLayout extends LinearLayout
{

    public MyLayout(Main context)
    {
        super(context);

    }

    public MyLayout(Context context,AttributeSet attribute)
    {
        super(context,attribute);       
    }

    protected  void onLayout (boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        super.onLayout(changed,l,t,r,b);

    }


}
```

Now the problem is that I want to perform draw operation using Canvas on one of the child Layout eg. Layout of id "widget38". How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

Put the views inside the bigger ones. You have to define them in a nested way, not sequentially, closing the parent layout after having defined the child layouts.

Comment: Hello Dhanesh, You means that I have to make same hierarchy as in xml in java file too ?

Comment: No, the layout hierarchy is defined in the XML. Java has nothing to do with the layout.